# Copy and Paste (cmd+c/cmd+v) Functionality with Ruby on Rails' Multi-Select Drop-Downs in Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails we can use form_helpers such as [select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) with the option `multiple: true` to create a form field that accepts multiple selections from a pre-populated list.

However, say we have a page that has several of these fields and the user is likely to choose similar options in each. It would be very helpful to the user to be able to copy and paste the options he/she selected in one field to another and then just edit what they need instead of reselecting all options in each.

**Is there any built-in rails form helper that allows copying and pasting selections from one to another?**

A possible way to implement this would be with an extra button next to each field that copies the results if clicked and another that pastes the results from clipboard if clicked. However, it would be great if there was a built in solution.

The screenshot below shows a situation where this would apply:
[image: page with 3 multi-select fields]

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about basic JavaScript stuff? e.g., https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: @anothermh This functionality can be implemented in JS. However, Rails (most of the time) abstracts the JS with its ERB helpers. The selectors shown on the sample above are 1-liners. I am wondering if there is a configuration I have not found or a well maintained extension that adds this functionality.